# Speedup VBA code to find rows with similar numbers occurrences

Tags: excel, vba

I have and excel filled with 0 and 1 like this one:
[image: Excel]

and I want to find which rows have three (1) in common with the others rows and delete them.

for example, to check with rows have three (1) in common with the first row I put this function in the column G :

G2:`=SUM.IF(A2:F2;"=1";A2:F2)`

G3:`=SUM.IF(A2:F2;"=1";A3:F3)`

G4:`=SUM.IF(A2:F2;"=1";A4:F4)`

G5:`=SUM.IF(A2:F2;"=1";A5:F5)`

and obviously I want to do this to a lot of Rows (5000++) and columns (51) and this is my code:

```
Sub Macro_NUEVA()

Dim maxRows, maxColumns, rowCount, row As Integer
maxRows= 10
maxColumns= 51
maxRows = InputBox("Number of rows?:", "Number of rows")

sngStartTime = Timer 'Just a timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Do not update screen to save some time

For rowCount = 2 To maxRows 'Iterate all Rows  

    For row = rowCount To maxRows 'loop to compare every single row with the actual row
      ActiveSheet.Cells(row, maxRows + 1).Select
      ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & Range("B" & rowCount & ":AY" & rowCount ).Address(False,     False) & ",""=1""," & Range("B" & row & ":AY" & row).Address(False, False) & ")"
        If Selection = 3 Then 'If three ones in common -> delete row
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        maxRows = maxRows - 1
        row= row- 1
      End If
  Next row 
Next rowCount

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
sngTotalTime = Timer - sngStartTime
MsgBox "Tiempo Empleado:  " & Round(sngTotalTime, 2) & " Segundos"

End Sub
```

This code is working fine, but it takes a lot of time... (7000 Rows -> 25 hours)

I'm a beginner with VBA, and I don't know if this code is efficient, but I didn't find any other way to solve the problem, also I'm thinking of doing this program in C (just parse a CSV).

Comment: There is a lot that can be improved upon but above all else, a canonical practise when deleting rows is to work from the bottom up as working down will often skip a row. However, in your unique circumstance this would change the way that the rules are adjudicated. Which is more important; working from the top-to-bottom and possibly missing a row or working from the bottom-to-top?

Comment: the parse order does not matter, it can be top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top, but I can't understand why its possible to miss a row when working top-to-bottom

Comment: If you are in a `For ... Next` loop and your increment variable is at 9 and you delete row 9 then increment to row 10 and continue the criteria based on that then you have effectively skipped over the old row 10 which is now row 9 when the original row 9 is deleted.

Comment: that's why I do this if I delete a row: row= row- 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this speeds things up for you. Tested on A2:AY5000 filled with `=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)` then copied & paste special values. Row 1 was a header row with column labels. You will need to rename your worksheet *Matriz* or modify the code line that names the worksheet.

[image: 5000×51 ones and zeroes]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro_NUEVA()
    Dim maxRws As Long, maxCols As Long, rwCount As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim f As Long, fc As Long, c As Long, cl As Long, rw As Long, n As Long
    Dim sngTime As Double, app As Application
    maxRws = 5000
    maxRws = InputBox("Número de filas?:", "Número de filas", maxRws)

    Set app = Application
    app.ScreenUpdating = False
    app.EnableEvents = False
    app.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    sngTime = Timer 'Just a timer

    Set ws = Sheets("Matriz")
    With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter
        On Error Resume Next: ws.ShowAllData: On Error GoTo 0
        maxCols = .Columns.Count
        For rw = 2 To maxRws
            For cl = 1 To (.Columns.Count - 2)
                If app.CountIf(.Cells(rw, cl).Resize(1, (maxCols - cl) + 1), 1) > 2 Then
                    f = 0
                    For fc = cl To maxCols
                        If .Cells(rw, fc).Value = 1 Then
                            .AutoFilter Field:=fc, Criteria1:=1
                            f = f + 1
                            If f = 3 Then Exit For
                        End If
                    Next fc
                    If f = 3 And app.Subtotal(102, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then
                        Debug.Print "deleting " & app.Subtotal(102, .Columns(1)) - 1 & " row(s)"
                        '.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        'next line is a modification of the offset to delete
                        .Offset(.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row, 0).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                    ws.ShowAllData
                End If
            Next cl
            If Not CBool(app.Count(Rows(rw + 1))) Then Exit For
        Next rw
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter
    End With
    Set ws = Nothing

    sngTime = Timer - sngTime
    MsgBox "Tiempo Empleado:  " & Round(sngTime, 2) & " Segundos"

    app.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    app.EnableEvents = False
    app.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set app = Application
End Sub
```

[image: results]

Your own elapsed time will depend greatly on the ratio of ones and zeroes. Mine was ~50%/50% if `RANDBETWEEN` was operating properly. More zeroes means more rows and columns have to be examined. You can check the VBE's *Immediate Window* for the count of rows that were deleted.

There are good reasons for not resetting your increment variable within a VBA `For ... Next`; a) getting caught in an infinite loop and b) not resetting the end of the loop means useless iterations are two of them. There are other reasons; in general it is not good programming methodology. In the above method, I don't have to worry about proceeding from top to bottom because I am leaving the row being examined alone and deleting every other match; not the other way around. I also have an exit when the row being examined no longer has any values.

I am a little curious about the purpose of this beyond an intellectual exercise. With 51 columns of >5000 rows with only a choice of *0* or *1* then there seems little chance that there would be much remaining after removing matching triplet sets of ones. Perhaps you could expand on that subject a bit in a comment or even your original posting.

Comment: +1 from me @Jeeped for the ideas and approach.  If we copied OPs original small data set down to row 5000, when the routine has finished shouldn't we end up with his top three (unique) rows? i.e. the only match being row 4 which should be deleted.  I end up with just row 1?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @barryleajo - thanks! I had been thinking about this more after posting it and I reworked the `.Offset` command in line 31 (...?). Was hoping to get some input from the OP before editing but I've submitted the modification to the post now. Another issue is that not all possible combination of triplet 1 matching are examined, only left-to-right progressive ones. If every combination was examined, I think you would have a better chance of winning the lottery than having a result of more than a single row. Again, thanks.

Comment: @barryleajo - well... I don't know about impressive but it isn't 23 hours ;)

Comment: I will test times tomorrow, but it looks a lot better than my code, the purpose of this is because a friend that works in a small shipping company wanted a macro to delete similar orders (the xml include size and data of the package) I can ask him for more details if you want

Comment: I have debugging the code, and I don't know why but this condition always false:    `If f = 3 And app.Subtotal(102, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then`  specifically `app.Subtotal(102, .Columns(1)) > 1 `

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez - the *f* refers to the previous loop having found 3 columns to filter on and the *Subtotal* is look for more than *1* number in column A. According to your sample data, that should work. I would imagine that the sample you posted was redacted sufficiently that the code does not work on the operational data. Did you run it on your sample data?.

Comment: @Jeeped If I try to run the macro in the sample I got an error (1004) on line 38 -> `ws.ShowAllData` I tried changing it to `If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If` but no success